# Python extremely dynamic class properties

Tags: python, class

To create a property in a class you simply do `self.property = value`. I want to be able to have the properties in this class completely dependent on a parameter. Let us call this class `Foo`.

instances of the `Foo` class would take a list of tuples:

```
l = [("first","foo"),("second","bar"),("anything","you get the point")]
bar = Foo(l)
```

now the instance of the `Foo` class we assigned to `bar` would have the following properties:

```
bar.first
#foo
bar.second
#bar
bar.anything
#you get the point
```

**Is this even remotely possible? How?**

Comment: Look at [`setattr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr).

Comment: You might also want to see [`namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).

Comment: setattr worked perfectly! thanks. and I'll look into namedtuple

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are called *attributes*, rather than *properties*. With that in mind, the method [`setattr()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) becomes more obvious:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, l):
        for k, v in l:
            setattr(self, k, v)
```

This takes each key-value pair in `l` and sets the attribute `k` on the new instance of `Foo` (`self`) to `v`.

Using your example:

```
l = [("first","foo"),("second","bar"),("anything","you get the point")]
bar = Foo(l)

print bar.first
#foo
print bar.second
#bar
print bar.anything
#you get the point
```

Comment: What's the difference with `setattr(Foo...` and `setattr(self...`?

Comment: I believe it is because self is each specific class where Foo is the general one so it will make all Foo classes have that. Not sure though, I'm just speculating

Comment: @Haidro: `self` sets the attribute for the current *instance*, rather than for the `class`.

Comment: @Johnsyweb Ah, so it's probably safer to use `self` :). +1

Answer (score 6):

I thought of another answer you could use using [`type()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type). It's completely different to my current answer so I've added a different answer:

```
>>> bar = type('Foo', (), dict(l))()
>>> bar.first
'foo'
>>> bar.second
'bar'
>>> bar.anything
'you get the point'
```

`type()` returns a *class*, not an *instance*, hence the extra `()` at the end.

Comment: this is extremely creative and compressed...+1

Comment: This is cool. Yesterday, I learnt to do the same in javascript with `Function` and today I learnt to do it in python. SO is OSM.

Comment: @thefourtheye: You can even build functions on the fly, using `types.FunctionType`. Of course you first need to get a code object (by compiling one, borrowing one from another function, generating bytecode by hand, …). Normally, there are better ways to do that in Python… but almost anything you can think of is possible.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to do this:

- Use `setattr` like this. This approach is feasible if you only need to process the initial list once, when the object is constructed.

  ```
  class Foo:
    def __init__(self, l):
      for (a, b) in l:
        setattr(self, a, b)
  ```
- Define a custom `__getattr__` method. Preferably, you would store the properties in a `dict` for faster lookup, but you can also search the original list. This is better if you want to later modify the list and want this to be reflected in the attributes of the object.

  ```
  class Foo:
    def __init__(self, l):
      self.l = l
    def __getattr__(self, name):
      for a in self.l:
        if a[0] == name:
          return a[1]
      return None
  ```

Comment: in `__getattr__` you need to have `self.l`, not `l`

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def __init__(self, mylist):
...         for k, v in mylist:
...             setattr(self, k, v)
... 
>>> l = [("first","foo"),("second","bar"),("anything","you get the point")]
>>> bar = Foo(l)
>>> bar.first
'foo'
>>> bar.second
'bar'
>>> bar.anything
'you get the point'
```

Using [`setattr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) you can do this by passing in the list and just iterating through it.

Answer (score -1):

setattr works.

```
>>> class Foo:
...   def __init__(self,yahoo):
...     for k,v in yahoo:
...       setattr(self,k,v)
...
>>> l = [("first","foo"),("second","bar"),("anything","you get the point")]
>>> bar = Foo(l)
>>> print bar.first
foo
>>> print bar.second
bar
>>> print bar.anything
you get the point
```